# Ubuntu Smbclient Error returning browse list: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, windows-server-2012-r2, samba, libsmbclient

I was trying to list the windows fileshare from Ubuntu server.
sometimes (no pattern) i can get a list of shares using

smbclient -L 10.1.31.11 -U domain/user%password

but after couple of times i am not able to get the list.
the error i get is ---

Domain=[domain] OS=[Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 9600] Server=[Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3]

```
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
```

tstream_smbXcli_np_destructor: cli_close failed on pipe srvsvc. Error was NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
Error returning browse list: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
Domain=[domain] OS=[Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 9600] Server=[Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3]

```
    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

any help would be appreciated as well as suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the protocol .
Added SMB2 in smb.conf file and it worked